# Plain JavaScript delete item from drop down select

Tags: javascript, dropdown

I got the two following `dropdown` lists and I want to remove the option chosen in either one. So if option 1 is chosen, it will not be there in list 2.

```
<select class='form-dropdown' name='first' id='first'>
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>

<select class='form-dropdown' name='second' id='second'>
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>
```

How is this possible in plain old JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

The Error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null` was solved by loading the EventListener in window.onload(), see below

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("change", function() {
        show_all("second");
        document.querySelector("#second option[value='"+this.value+"']").style.display="none";
    });


    document.getElementById("second").addEventListener("change", function() {
        show_all("first");
        document.querySelector("#first option[value='"+this.value+"']").style.display="none";
    });

};

function show_all(select_name){
    var second_options = document.querySelectorAll("#"+select_name+" option");

    for(var i=0;i<second_options.length;i++){
        second_options[i].style.display="block";
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better to populate second dropdown with values from first, every time when first value is changed?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xh3qb8r6/

Comment: my problem is, that my form, which has three of this lists don't work with code like Zer00ne provided down, so I thought this is because of JQuery stuff or so. That's also why i wanted a plain JavaScript Solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add change event to the first `select` then hide the option in second list that have the same value of the current selected, and you could add another function called `show_all()` to show all the options before hidding the selected one :

```js
function show_all(){
  var second_options = document.querySelectorAll("#second option");
  for(var i=0;i<second_options.length;i++){
    second_options[i].style.display="block";
  }  
  document.getElementById("second").value='none';
}

document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("change", function() {
  show_all();

  document.querySelector("#second option[value='"+this.value+"']").style.display="none";
});
```

```html
<select class='form-dropdown' name='first' id='first'>
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>

<select class='form-dropdown' name='second' id='second'>
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>
```

---

If you want to avoid the duplicate selection in the both lists you could use :

```js
function show_all(select_name){
  var second_options = document.querySelectorAll("#"+select_name+" option");
  
  for(var i=0;i<second_options.length;i++){
    second_options[i].style.display="block";
  }  
}

document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("change", function() {
  show_all("second");
  document.querySelector("#second option[value='"+this.value+"']").style.display="none";
})

document.getElementById("second").addEventListener("change", function() {
  show_all("first");
  document.querySelector("#first option[value='"+this.value+"']").style.display="none";
})
```

```html
<select class='form-dropdown' name='first' id='first'>
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>

<select class='form-dropdown' name='second' id='second'>
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>
```

Comment: Assuming it wasn't just a reaction to a high rep user answering a question which should be closed as it lacks any effort... I'd suggest it could be because you can reach an invalid state in this case: if the user selects from the second set before selecting the first, then the same value can be selected twice (as hiding options doesn't deselect them).

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki if I try you second code i get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null

Comment: That mean it can't find one of the selects by id `first` or `second` just make sure that you have those ids.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I'm sure that I have those id's in my html code. Is it possible, that this only works with jquery?

Comment: No, theres no jquery code in the answer, try to use `.addEventListener()` check my update.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null`  .

Comment: @SvenBamberger try to place you JS in the end of body `tag`.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Hi, for the second solution, what should I add if I have more than 2 dropdowns? for example, I have 4? I tried to add but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi Zorev, do you still need this?

Answer (score 1):

Just have a look at this code , working fine for me

```
<html>
<select class='form-dropdown' name='first' id='first' onchange="fun1(this.value)">
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>

<select class='form-dropdown' name='second' id='second' onchange="fun2(this.value)">
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select></html>

<script>

function fun1(val){
    updateFun2(val)
}

function fun2(val){
    updateFun1(val)
}

function updateFun2(val){
    selectobject=document.getElementById('second');
     for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
      if (selectobject.options[i].value == val )
         selectobject.remove(i);
      }
}

function updateFun1(val){
    selectobject=document.getElementById('first');
     for (var i=0; i<selectobject.length; i++){
      if (selectobject.options[i].value == val )
         selectobject.remove(i);
      }
}

</script>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki thats what i also experienced, so i removed the check. First i thought this would work.

Answer (score 1):

HTML CODE :-

```
<select class='form-dropdown' name='first' id='first'>
<option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
<option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
<option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
<option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
<option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
<option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>

<select class='form-dropdown' name='second' id='second'>
    <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
    <option value='Workshop 1'> Workshop 1 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 2'> Workshop 2 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 3'> Workshop 3 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 4'> Workshop 4 </option>
    <option value='Workshop 5'> Workshop 5 </option>
</select>
```

Javascript Code :-

```
var first  = document.getElementById('first');
var second = document.getElementById('second');
var optionOld = document.createElement("option");

first.addEventListener('change', function() {
     var option = second.querySelector('option[value="' + this.value + '"]');
     if(optionOld.text != '')
     {
       second.add(optionOld);
       }
            optionOld = option;
            second.removeChild(option);
});
```

I have changed some code in adeneo JSfiddler.

Please check it working on my environment.

Also Find fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/xh3qb8r6/1/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `change` event listener on the first dropdown, check the value of it, and remove the element from the second dropdown which has the same value:

```
document.getElementById("first").addEventListener("change", event=> {
  if (event.target.value === "none") return

  document.querySelector(`#second [value="${event.target.value}"]`).remove()
})
```

See demo on [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/dacogu/edit?html,js,output).

Answer (score 0):

## Update

I realized that just using the index wasn't working right since `#second` would diminish in length and it's index would change as well. So I added a `for` loop to iterate through `#second` and upon a match of values between `#first` and `#second`  options, the index is used to target the matching option and then it's removed.

- on the `change` event...
- Get the index of the `#first` `<option>` selected.
- Store index in var, and...
- Use **[`.remove(index)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove)** targeting `#second`

```js
var first = document.getElementById('first');


first.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var second = document.getElementById('second');
  var selected = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
   for (var i=0; i<second.length; i++){
     if (second.options[i].value == selected )
     second.remove(i);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<select class='form-dropdown' name='first' id='first'>
  <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
  <option value='Workshop 1'>Workshop 1</option>
  <option value='Workshop 2'>Workshop 2</option>
  <option value='Workshop 3'>Workshop 3</option>
  <option value='Workshop 4'>Workshop 4</option>
  <option value='Workshop 5'>Workshop 5</option>
</select>

<select class='form-dropdown' name='second' id='second'>
  <option value='none' selected>No Choice</option>
  <option value='Workshop 1'>Workshop 1</option>
  <option value='Workshop 2'>Workshop 2</option>
  <option value='Workshop 3'>Workshop 3</option>
  <option value='Workshop 4'>Workshop 4</option>
  <option value='Workshop 5'>Workshop 5</option>
</select>
```