# Selection list disabled in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning HTML and JavaScript, and I would like to know how to edit my selection list to prevent users from selecting the same thing.

The code below shows one of the listboxes. The second list contains the same entries, (I have a total of 10 lists.) By using pure JavaScript, (not jQuery), I'd like to know how to prevent the user from selecting an identical entry in all 10 of the listboxes?

```js
function display(choice,row)
 { 
  var total = 0; 
  document.getElementById("price" + row).value = choice;
    }
```

```html
<select id="mov1" name="mov1" onchange="display(this.value,1)" >
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a movie</option>
    <option id="1" value="4.99">17 Again (2009)</option>
    <option id="2" value="13.20">Avatar The Last Airbender (2010)</option>
    <option id="3" value="0.70">Batman Begins (2005)</option>
    <option id="4" value="14.25">Deadpool (2016)</option>
    <option id="5" value="1.08">Elysium (2013)</option>
    <option id="6" value="10.11">Fast And Furious 7 (2015)</option>
    <option id="7" value="4.89">Fifty Shades Of Grey (2015)</option>
    <option id="8" value="6.99">Goosebumps (2015)</option>
    <option id="9" value="10.95">Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows Part 2 (2011)</option>
    <option id="10" value="2.45">I Am Number 4 (2011)</option>
    <option id="11" value="0.89">Jack And The Giant Slayer (2013)</option>
    <option id="12" value="5.39">Kingsman The Secret Service (2014)</option>
    <option id="13" value="0.71">Lord Of The Rings (2001)</option>
    <option id="14" value="6.50">Maleficent (2014)</option>
    <option id="15" value="0.72">Mean Girls (2004)</option>
    <option id="16" value="6.40">Minions (2015)</option>
    <option id="17" value="9.90">Mission Impossible Rogue Nation (2015)</option>
    <option id="18" value="6.39">Now You See Me (2013)</option>
    <option id="19" value="2.40">Oz The Great And Powerful (2013)</option>
    <option id="20" value="5.00">Percy Jackson And The Lightning Thief (2010)</option>
    <option id="21" value="8.09">Pirates Of the Caribbean On The Stranger Tides (2011)</option>
    <option id="22" value="9.46">Quantum Of Solace (2008)</option>
    <option id="23" value="4.23">Rise Of The Guardians (2012)</option>
    <option id="24" value="0.73">Shrek The Third (2007)</option>
    <option id="25" value="4.61">Snow White And The Huntsman (2011)</option>
    <option id="26" value="4.33">Spring Breakers (2012)</option>
    <option id="27" value="0.74">The Hunger Games (2012)</option>
    <option id="28" value="0.75">The Sisterhood Of The Traveling Pants (2005)</option>
    <option id="29" value="1.06">Ultraviolet (2006)</option>
    <option id="30" value="1.83">Vampire Academy (2014)</option>
    <option id="31" value="2.77">World War Z (2013)</option>
    <option id="32" value="0.76">X-Men Origins Wolverine (2009)</option>
    <option id="33" value="1.99">Yogi Bear (2010)</option>
   </select>
<input type="text" style="text-align:center" name="price1" id="price1" readonly="readonly" size=8>
```

Comment: where is your second list?

Comment: @Reddy I think second list is identical to the first but you can't pick the same movie twice.

Comment: Please provide the full code snippet inclusive your JavaScript so far.

Comment: @Reddy its the same list just the id="mov1" changed to id="mov2"

Comment: you add an event listener for `change` for both the select elements and when any select element is changed, you can disable the selected option in the other select box.

Comment: @redflar3 um, im a total newbie in JavaScript, what actually is an event listener?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone I updated the code... ru able to understand better?

Comment: Ok, i see you haven't touched any solution yet. I've edited your question to clarify your problem. Is it correct like that?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone yes! Thanks for the edit!

Comment: What does the `value` mean? Is it a price, duration time or something else that can occur duplicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try not to use inline event handlers, use `.addEventListener()`instead.
- Detect a change event on `#mov1`
- Determine `#mov1` selection with `selectedIndex` then determine it's value
- Next iterate through the options of `#mov2` with a `for` loop.
- Match the value of each iteration to the selected value of `#mov1`.
- If there's a match, remove `#mov2`'s option with `.remove(i)`

Question is simular to this one : https://stackoverflow.com/a/36234342/2813224

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/ceFXiE3vVf966Km3wvck?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the code you have provided, but i got a few questions...all the mov1 and mov2 is fixed there in the javascript but i have 10 selections (means mov1 until mov10) in total. If I wanted to change for all of them means that I need to copy, paste, edit for 10 times?

Comment: You are using mov1 a select with 10 options and mov2 which is identical to mov1. When did mov3 thru mov10 come into the question? Btw id cannot start with a number. Anyways, that's another question because I'd show you how to do that programmatically.

Comment: i only show 10 option but in total i have 34 option cause its a bit too long so i cut it down.

Comment: so i have a total of 10 select and 34 options in all of them

Comment: It'd be the same answer, it's a whole different thing to generate elements because you don't want to do it manually.

Comment: So you meant that im suppose to copy paste edit for 10 times to get the things im looking for?

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean things you are looking for? The nature of a select is that there a set number of options. You have another list that is identical. The other selects are predetermined just like the first two you have.

Comment: This is your question:*The second list contains the same entries. By using pure JavaScript(not JQuery), how is it possible to prevent the user from selecting an identical entry in both of the listboxes?* If you want to clone elements ask another question.

Comment: I'm sorry if I made you confused, I edited a bit of the question...hope you can understand better

Comment: Nested loops would work, one `for` loop for each of them. Why would you need 10 copies of 34  separate items? Something this repetitive might be better handled by using arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Use *unique element IDs* per *hole page*. Number as IDs are not very expressive. The `value` attribute should tell the server what has been selected. Further data can be placed in `data-...` attributes or you hold it in an array.

JavaScript

```
var prices =
[ 1.99,
  2.99,
  3.99,
  3.99,
  2.99,
  1.99,
  3.49,
  3.49,
  1.99,
  1.99
];

function onChange(event)
{ 
  if(/^mov\d+$/.test(event.target.id))
  {
    var itemsToDisable = document.querySelectorAll('.mov-list:not(#' + event.target.id + ')>option[value="'+ event.target.value +'"]');

    if(event.target.disabledItems)
      for(var i=0 ; i<event.target.disabledItems.length ; i++)
        event.target.disabledItems[i].disabled = false;

    for(var i=0 ; i<itemsToDisable.length ; i++)
      itemsToDisable[i].disabled = true;

    event.target.disabledItems = itemsToDisable;

    console.log(prices[event.target.value]);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('change', onChange);
```

HTML

```
<div>
  <select id="mov0" class="mov-list" name="mov1">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a movie</option>
    <option value="0" data-price="1.99">17 Again (2009)</option>
    <option value="1">Avatar The Last Airbender (2010)</option>
    <option value="2">Batman Begins (2005)</option>
    <option value="3">Deadpool (2016)</option>
    <option value="4">Elysium (2013)</option>
    <option value="5">Fast And Furious 7 (2015)</option>
    <option value="6">Fifty Shades Of Grey (2015)</option>
    <option value="7">Goosebumps (2015)</option>
    <option value="8">Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows Part 2 (2011)</option>
    <option value="9">I Am Number 4 (2011)</option>
   </select>
  <select id="mov1" class="mov-list" name="mov2">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a movie</option>
    <option value="0">17 Again (2009)</option>
    <option value="1">Avatar The Last Airbender (2010)</option>
    <option value="2">Batman Begins (2005)</option>
    <option value="3">Deadpool (2016)</option>
    <option value="4">Elysium (2013)</option>
    <option value="5">Fast And Furious 7 (2015)</option>
    <option value="6">Fifty Shades Of Grey (2015)</option>
    <option value="7">Goosebumps (2015)</option>
    <option value="8">Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows Part 2 (2011)</option>
    <option value="9">I Am Number 4 (2011)</option>
  </select>
  <select id="mov2" class="mov-list" name="mov2">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select a movie</option>
    <option value="0">17 Again (2009)</option>
    <option value="1">Avatar The Last Airbender (2010)</option>
    <option value="2">Batman Begins (2005)</option>
    <option value="3">Deadpool (2016)</option>
    <option value="4">Elysium (2013)</option>
    <option value="5">Fast And Furious 7 (2015)</option>
    <option value="6">Fifty Shades Of Grey (2015)</option>
    <option value="7">Goosebumps (2015)</option>
    <option value="8">Harry Potter And The Deathly Hallows Part 2 (2011)</option>
    <option value="9">I Am Number 4 (2011)</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // ...
</script>
```